# Prestashop 1.6 : Reset date in cart when Update

Tags: cart, prestashop-1.6

I have a selected date when I choose a carrier.
I try to reset this date to zero if I modify my cart.

I tried with ActionCartSave() hook but it does not take place when I add or remove an item from my cart, but just before the validation of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with this hook:

`actionBeforeCartUpdateQty`

this hook is located in `Cart::updateQty` and it's fired before adding, updating and deleting product.